# gspread - NameError: name 'set_with_dataframe' is not defined

Tags: gspread

I've been successfully running the gspread function set_with_dataframe(sheet, df) in Google Colab, but when running it in Databricks, I receive the following error:

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account_from_dict(variables)
title = "Workbook name"
workbook = gc.create(title)
sheet = gc.open(title).sheet1
set_with_dataframe(sheet, df)

---> 16   set_with_dataframe(sheet, df)

NameError: name 'set_with_dataframe' is not defined
```

I am running gspread version 4.0.1.

It seems the other gspread methods related to the gspread client are working, but this function isn't a method.

Any ideas on how to make this run successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't clear from the documentation, but it looks like set_with_dataframe may be part of a related but separate package: `gspread-dataframe` (https://pypi.org/project/gspread-dataframe/3.2.1/)

My code worked by adding

```
pip install gspread-dataframe==3.2.1
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
```

I don't know why this step wasn't necessary when using Google colab - maybe these packages are pre-installed there?